# nfs does not mount on boot

Tags: boot, mount, startup, nfs, remote

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 on Azure and i mounted an nfs. fstab looks like:

```
192.168.2.2:/nfs-share  mnt/nfs-share   nfs   defaults,nolock,_netdev   0 2
```

This works perfectly fine but when the VM boots, nfs cannot be mounted automatically.

The logs show:

```
[  OK  ] Started ifup for eth0.
         Starting Raise network interfaces...
[  OK  ] Started Raise network interfaces.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
         Starting Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler)...
[  OK  ] Stopped target Remote File Systems.
[  OK  ] Unmounted mnt/nfs-share.
[  OK  ] Unmounted /mnt.
```

Any ideas why does Remote File Systems stop and nfs mount fails?

Answer (score 0):

Without having more details of your configuration, the only thing I can suggest is to modify the options on your /etc/fstab entry to the following:

```
auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

Make sure you create a backup of your current configuration before you make any changes.